# Error in SQL Update Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I am trying to update a database via an update query,but I am getting an error that says

```
Error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add=null,col=null,wok=null,pcol=null,pwok=null,bio=null where un ='null'' at line 1.
```

I have been trying for hours to figure out what the error is in my SQL Syntax,but I haven't been able to get through.

The update query is:

```
query = "Update users SET em=?, mn=?,add=?,col=?,wok=?,pcol=?,pwok=?,bio=? where un ='"+un+"'";
```

I need help in figuring out the error in my update syntax,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD is a reserved word in mysql use backticks

```
\`add\`=?
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Answer (score 1):

ADD is reserved word. Please quote it or change field name

Answer (score 1):

From [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

the word `add` is a reserved keyword

> Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as
>   described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”:

From [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html)

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever
>   you refer to it.